# Lambda timeout after 29s, unable to find request ID in CloudWatch logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless

I'm new to AWS and Node so I really appreciate everyone's suggestion on this one. Recently in my system, something strange happened. Sometimes (~20 times/ month), a lambda request got timeout. It's just a simple request in middleware for authentication (I'm using node.JS serverless). The issues is I cannot trace this request from API gateway. Sorry I'm suck at explaining things so I'm gonna put it like this:

My system's flow: CloudFront -> API Gateway -> Lambda -> RDS

Normally if I want to trace a request:
I get the requestID from Lambda's Log

[image]

And search it in the API Gateway's Log:

[image]

But for these Timeout request:

[image]

I cannot find anything at all in API Gateway's Log:

[image]

Like it appeared out of nowhere... Please help and thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: try and use aws x-ray service for tracing the end to end flow of use case involving multiple service

Comment: As you query in cloudWatch, you should use requestID instead of message bcz you are searching the requestID not any logger message.

Answer (score 4):

You may already be aware but [API Gateway has a hard max timeout limit of 29 seconds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html) and stops waiting for the integration to respond after that time.

The Request ID that you are pulling from the lambda logs is the lambda request ID.  This is a bit of speculation but I'm guessing since the Lambda took longer than 29 seconds and never returned to API Gateway since API Gateway timed out and stopped waiting, the API Gateway never received a response from the Lambda function to know what the lambda request ID is.

There still should be some API Gateway logs for this invocation but it won't contain any of the normal integration response log lines because it never received a response from the lambda integration.

Perhaps try searching for `504` in the API Gateway logs since this is the response code when the gateway times out.

Or as AADProgramming recommends, the X Ray service was designed to help users track requests across many services so enabling that would be helpful here.